# Product of maps/morphisms (category theory) notation and proof.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, notation

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson and I'm in the section titled "Categories and Functors"

To put the title question in context, here's the question taken from the text

Let $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an indexed family of categories with objects $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ and maps $\{H_\alpha(X,Y)\}_{\alpha\in I}$. Let $A=\prod_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha$. For $U,V\in A$ let $H(U,V)=\prod_{\alpha\in I} (H_\alpha(U(\alpha),V(\alpha)))$. For $f\in H(U,V), g\in H(V,W)$ define $gf(\alpha)=f(\alpha)g(\alpha)$. Prove that this yields a category $C=\prod_{\alpha\in I} C_\alpha$ with objects $A$ and maps $H(U,V)$.

I have a few questions on both notation and how to actually attempt to prove this problem.

1. What are the $\alpha$'s in $U(\alpha)$ and $V(\alpha)$ supposed to represent? Are they elements in $U$ and $V$ or just place holders for the index?
2. Are the $\alpha$'s in $f(\alpha)$ or $g(\alpha)$ actual inputs for the functions or are they place holders? I recognize that Mendelson used $\alpha$ as an element in the index $I$, but I can't quite see the connection.
3. To begin proving this, from the way $gf$ defined, would showing associativity be $h(gf)(\alpha)=h(\alpha)g(\alpha)f(\alpha)=(hg)f(\alpha)$? Or am I wrong in my understanding of $gf$? I really do want to figure this out, yet without understanding the notation completely, I don't want to approach the rest of the proof.

Thanks for any ideas/hints/feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $U, V$ are elements of $A = \prod_{α ∈ I} A_α$ so $U = ⟨U(α): α ∈ I⟩$ with each $U(α) ∈ A_α$.
2. Same as in 1. $f, g$ are just $I$-tuples of morphisms of corresponding categories between corresponding objects.
3. Yes, you are right. More precisely $[h(gf)](α) = h(α)[gf](α) = h(α)(g(α)f(α)) = h(α)g(α)f(α)$. Same for the other half. Since the composition is defined coordinatewise, the asociativity transfers from acosiativity of composing coordinate morphism.

Actually this product construction is same as any product construction – just define everything coordinatewise. It's like e.g. product of groups. Actually a category is a structure just like group. If you focus on morphisms as elements of the structure then category is just a partial monoid. It's like monoid but the binary operation is not total function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up some issues. I do have a follow up question though. On how you defined $U$, does the brackets you wrote mean product of $U(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha\in I$?

Comment: It's just alternative notation for function emphasizing our view on it as tuple of coordinates. $f: X \to Y$ then $f = ⟨f(x): x ∈ X⟩$. In our case $U$ is element of $\prod_{α ∈ I} A_α$ so it is a function like that (that's from definition of cartesian product of sets).